# Setting up OpenCV 2.4.2 on MS Visual Express 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv

I'm trying to set up OpenCV2.4.2 in VS2010 but not succeeding. I downloaded the OpenCV file on sourceforge.net to the directory `C:\Opencv`, and lib folder is missing as expected.

When trying to build/generate library files using the guide from the OpenCV wiki, the SVN repository generator fails to download, although I'm connected to the internet wirelessly.

I have tried to set up OpenCV2.1 on VS2008 and that worked without major problems.

Is there an easier way to get the required library files, etc., without much sweat?

Comment: Unless you want only the latest code, you can try the binary installer that they provide

Comment: I think the problem must be with the networking side, though I never experience problems when accessing the Internet. I chose to install opencv2.3.1, and it's working fine so far. Thx for comments...

Comment: What do you mean by "problem with networking side"?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear there, but I meant the part of the setup that requires connecting to the Internet for download. Besides the problem above, I've never experienced problems with Internet.

Comment: @go4sri Thx for your comments. Was able to setup openCV 2.4.2. Now started working on some example programs. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It feels a bit awkward to answer your own question, but let me do it. I followed this link < http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kZvjTTK9zTw > to install OpenCV 2.3.1. I thought it was not working as I could not load the image successfully.

Apparently, I made one big mistake: the image file extension. The name of the file was ending with .jpg, and I was trying to load the 'filename', changed it, then it worked fine.

Following the link above was, for me, even simpler than the opencv.org tutorial. I imagine following the same instructions as in the video would also apply for OpenCV 2.4.2.

Thx all...
Ruzzar